# set a right margin to epigraph

Tags: spacing

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\setlength{\epigraphrule}{0pt}
\setlength\epigraphwidth{.65\textwidth}
\begin{document}
\epigraph{\itshape Si l'univers était vide, on s'éviterait bien des soucis}{(Lao Tseu)}
\section{Introduction}
\end{document}
```

How do I align the author to end at the same line as the quote.

This would be the end result
[image]

Comment: It is not clear what you want. Do you want to move the italic text to left margin?

Comment: I want to move the author to the left, so that they both end at the same x coordinate

Comment: Like this: `\epigraph{\hfill\itshape Si l'univers était vide, on s'éviterait bien des soucis}{(Lao Tseu)}` ?

Comment: that aligned the italic text to the author, I want the opposite :)

Comment: But you said *...end at the same x coordinate*. This is the case. Or do you want aligned to left (`(` below `S`)?

Comment: I have edited my question, sorry, I mean to move the author to the left so that it ends at the same line as the italic text

Comment: Not at all sure what you want. If the quote is short do you want the author moved left? But if the quote is short should it be moved right to align with the author? That is, what is your desired layout for long and short epigraphs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\setlength{\epigraphrule}{0pt}
\setlength\epigraphwidth{.65\textwidth}
\renewcommand{\textflush}{flushright}
\begin{document}
\epigraph{\itshape Si l'univers était vide, on s'éviterait bien des soucis}{(Lao Tseu)}
\section{Introduction}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\setlength{\epigraphrule}{0pt}
\setlength\epigraphwidth{.65\textwidth}
\renewcommand{\textflush}{flushright}
\renewcommand{\epigraphflush}{flushleft}
\begin{document}
\epigraph{\itshape Si l'univers était vide, on s'éviterait bien des soucis}{(Lao Tseu)}
\section{Introduction}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very easy. Could `\textflush` affect something else?

Comment: @Sigur no, it is the documented interface.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

[image]

If yes, you don't need the `epigraph` package. Use the `\epigraph{}{}` command as below.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{showframe} % just to show margin frame

\newcommand{\epigraph}[2]{%
\par\medskip%
\hfill%
\begin{tabular}{@{}r@{\hspace{2in}}}
\itshape #1\\
(#2)
\end{tabular}
\par\medskip%
}

\begin{document}
\epigraph{Si l'univers était vide, on s'éviterait bien des soucis}{Lao Tseu}

\section{title}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I would like the ")" to be right underneath the last "s" and both lines to have a right-margin of a some inches(e.g. 2)

Comment: So, replace the tabular alignments. Use `@{}r@{\hspace*{2in}}` instead.